# SolrCloud on different machines

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have setup a Solr cloud on two machines, I created a collection `collection1` and split it into two shards with 2 replica's, I added my other Solr machine to the cloud and in the Solr admin page in `cloud->tree->live nodes`, I can see 4 live, which includes the last Solr instance launched, but I can see my shards are running on the same machine just on different ports, even replica is still showing the leader address.

Now I want to shift the replica to the newly launched Solr instance or just put the entire shard 1 or 2 on the other machines.

I have tried searching about it, but nothing tells me the exact commands.

Comment: so, you want to move replica/shard from one node to another, correct?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i want

Answer (score 0):

This question is rather old, but for the sake of completeness:

1. In the Solr UI goto *Collections*
2. Select your collection
3. Click on the shards on the right side
4. Click *add replica*
5. Choose your new node as the target node
6. Wait for the replica to be ready (watch in *Cloud > Graph*)
7. Back in the shards list, delete the old replica
8. If the old replica was the leader, a leader election will be triggered automatically.